# Angular Material md-menu element does not close if clicked outside on a fixed element with z-index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have a basic `<md-menu>` element within my document. On default, it will close itself if clicked anywhere within the document. Although, if I click inside a `fixed` element with a `z-index`, it will not close.

```
<div class="menu-demo-container" layout-align="center center" layout="column">
  <md-menu>
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="ctrl.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
      Test
    </md-button>
    <md-menu-content width="4">
      <md-menu-item>
        <md-button>
          Menu Item
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
</div>

<div style="position:fixed; z-index: 100; backgorund-color:red;left:0;top:0;bottom:0">
  Try clicking here while the the md-menu is open
</div>
```

How can I get all my `<md-menu>` elements to close if I click anywhere outside of it, including on fixed elements?

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZEwGp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem with `z-index` of element, which is greater then backdrop's `z-index`. It's possible to close menu by click on `md-backdrop` element. `md-backdrop.md-menu-backdrop` has `z-index` equal to 99.

> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.

To resolve a problem, reduce z-index of element. In your case, it should be less than `99`

Comment: **Don't forget to move `.md-scroll-mask` also!** Otherwise the user can interact with the page while your menu is open.